# Java Move File and apply Attributes of Directory in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I actually try to move a File in Java and apply the attributes to the new File of the directory.
Is there any good way to do it?
I actually move the file via `Files.move` unfortunatly `StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES` will throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`.
Is there another way of actually copying the file with attributes?

I only now of a way to copy the file and then remove the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Try java.io.File renameTo (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
File originalFile = new File("filePath")
File newFile = new File("newFilePath");
boolean result = originalFile.renameTo(newFile);
```